# Encountering error sql_mode=only_full_group_by so how do I get the results I need

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL query, trying to calculate the lowest Price for a each VendorPartNumber, but I keep getting sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The table has multiple rows with the same VendorPartNumber, each with a unique ProductID.
I understand what the error is for, and why it occurs, but in this occasion, I cannot figure how to get around it and get the answers that I want.

This is what I want to do, but gives me the Full Group error

```sql
SELECT *,min(p.Price) as mPrice
FROM 
    `Products` as p
WHERE p.Active
Group BY p.VendorPartNumber
```

I understand that I get the error because mysql does not know which of the multiple records with a single VendorPartNumber to return with the min(Price) value.  It can't return the row that has the min price, either, because probably several products with the same VendorPartNumber have the same price.

I can do this

```sql
SELECT min(p.Price) as mPrice,`VendorPartNumber`
FROM 
    `Products` as p
WHERE p.Active
Group BY p.VendorPartNumber
```

But then I don't get all the other row information that I need.  Or I can do this

```sql
SELECT *,min(p.Price) as mPrice
FROM 
    `Products` as p
WHERE p.Active
Group BY p.VendorPartNumber, p.ProductID
```

But that splits the VendorPartNumbers and no longer calculates the minimum Price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this because I've figured it out when apparently no one else could ;)

Thanks to this article for pointing me in the right direction: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/
I can concatenate the ProductIDs, and any other values I want, I can use the ANY_VALUE() function (or Min(), Max()).
In my case, the Name column will be essentially the same for each product with the same VendorPartNumber

```sql
SELECT Group_Concat(`ProductID`) as ids,`VendorPartNumber`, min(Price) as mPrice, Any_Value(Name) as name, Max(Stock) as stock
FROM `Products` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY VendorPartNumber
```

This query allows me to pull the information I need, and still calculate the min price